# Convert declared id into an array

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to change this line into an array

```
private $formId = '1';
```

Tried:

```
private $formId = array('1', '2');
```

But it didn't work.
I'm a novice when it comes to programming, any help much appreciated :)

Comment: you can initialize your class properties into constructor.

Comment: What exactly needed? explain clearly?

Comment: what error do you get???

Comment: `private $formId = array('1', '2');` is a valid expression and should work when defining a class property.So the problem is elsewhere....

Comment: I think you are correct George, the problem is elsewhere I believe..

Answer (score 2):

try

```
private $formId = ['1', '2'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize any Class Property inside the constructor. Imagine the following Class:

```
    class FormManager{
        private $formId;
        private $formName;
        private $formMethod;

        public function __construct() {
            // YOU CAN SET ANY VALUES TO ANY OF THE PROPERTIES OF THIS CLASS
            // HERE SO THAT EACH OBJECT CREATED FROM THIS CLASS WOULD HAVE
            // THE INITIAL VALUES SET HERE WITHIN THE CONSTRUCTOR
            $this->formId     = array('1', '2');
            $this->formMethod = "POST";
            $this->formName   = "base_form";
        }

        /**
         * @return array|null
         */
        public function getFormId() {
            return $this->formId;
        }

        /**
         * @param array|null $formId
         * @return FormManager
         */
        public function setFormId($formId) {
            $this->formId = $formId;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * @return null|string
         */
        public function getFormMethod() {
            return $this->formMethod;
        }

        /**
         * @param null|string $formMethod
         * @return FormManager
         */
        public function setFormMethod($formMethod) {
            $this->formMethod = $formMethod;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * @return null|string
         */
        public function getFormName() {
            return $this->formName;
        }

        /**
         * @param null|string $formName
         * @return FormManager
         */
        public function setFormName($formName) {
            $this->formName = $formName;

            return $this;
        }
    }
```

Here, below is another Variant where the Constructor accepts 3 Arguments:

```
    class FormManager{
        private $formId;
        private $formName;
        private $formMethod;

        /**
         * FormManager constructor.
         * @param $formId
         * @param $formMethod
         * @param $formName
         */
        public function __construct($formId=null, $formMethod=null, $formName=null) {
            // YOU CAN SET ANY VALUES TO ANY OF THE PROPERTIES OF THIS CLASS
            // HERE SO THAT EACH OBJECT CREATED FROM THIS CLASS WOULD HAVE
            // THE INITIAL VALUES SET HERE WITHIN THE CONSTRUCTOR.
            // THE ARGUMENTS HERE ARE OPTIONAL & THEY DEFAULT EACH TO NULL.
            // UNLESS AN ARGUMENT IS SUPPLIED, THE VALUES YOU SET HERE FOR
            // EACH OF THE PROPERTIES OVERRIDE THE NULLS...
            $this->formId     = ( isset($formId)     && !is_null($formId) )         ? $formId       : array('1', '2');
            $this->formMethod = ( isset($formMethod) && !is_null($formMethod) )  ? $formMethod   : "POST";
            $this->formName   = ( isset($formName)   && !is_null($formName) )   ? $formName     : "base_form";
        }

        /**
         * @return array|null
         */
        public function getFormId() {
            return $this->formId;
        }

        /**
         * @param array|null $formId
         * @return FormManager
         */
        public function setFormId($formId) {
            $this->formId = $formId;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * @return null|string
         */
        public function getFormMethod() {
            return $this->formMethod;
        }

        /**
         * @param null|string $formMethod
         * @return FormManager
         */
        public function setFormMethod($formMethod) {
            $this->formMethod = $formMethod;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * @return null|string
         */
        public function getFormName() {
            return $this->formName;
        }

        /**
         * @param null|string $formName
         * @return FormManager
         */
        public function setFormName($formName) {
            $this->formName = $formName;

            return $this;
        }
    }
```

Using the Constructor, you can initialize the `$formId`, `$formMethod` & `$formName`. Notice that all arguments in the Constructor have default values of `NULL`. This was intentional - only to demonstrate the possibility of initializing the Member Variables to any values you may like during Object Construction.